# Convert text fields in movieclips in Flash with jsfl

Tags: flash, jsfl

I need basically a way to convert a group of selected text in movieclips separately with Flash commands. For example, I know to select just text items in the stage is:

```
var theSelectionArray = fl.getDocumentDOM().selection;

for(var i = 0; i < theSelectionArray.length; i++){

    if(theSelectionArray[i].elementType == "text"){
       ...    
    }
}
```

And I know to convert a selection in a movieclip is:

```
fl.getDocumentDOM().convertToSymbol("movie clip", theName, "top left");
```

So I need to know the way to loop over the stage and convert each text field in a movieclip.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you select all the objects and iterate over them as in your example?

```
var startIndex = prompt("Please enter the start index", "0");
if (startIndex == null || startIndex.length == 0) {
    startIndex = 0;
};
startIndex = parseInt(startIndex); // Just to be on the safe side.

fl.getDocumentDOM().selectAll();
var theSelectionArray = fl.getDocumentDOM().selection;
for(var i = 0; i < theSelectionArray.length; i++){
    if(theSelectionArray[i].elementType == "text") {
        fl.getDocumentDOM().selectNone();
        fl.getDocumentDOM().selection = [theSelectionArray[i]];
        fl.getDocumentDOM().convertToSymbol("movie clip", "textfield" + startIndex, "top left");
        startIndex++;
    }
}
```

Edited: the code above works now. (with a start index.)

Comment: The problem with that script is that it will create "n" movieclips with all current selection, not just the text.

For example this is similar what I need (but it does not work):


fl.getDocumentDOM().theSelectionArray[i].convertToSymbol("movie clip", "textfield" + i, "top left");

Comment: It wasn't that off the mark. :) Please see the edited code in the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! it works like a charm!

One more question, it's possible after I run the command, if I run the command again continue in the last "i" created? I mean, if I run the command in the last MovieClip created the name will be "textfield7" (for example), but if I run the command later the next MovieClip is  "textfield8" not "textfield1" again.

Thanks you saved my life!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of a way to persist data accross scripts. However you can give it an index to start with. See the updated code above.